# Unble to call the node server from the vue.js dev environnment

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have a vue project, src is the vue app directory , server.js is the node backend file :

```
/dist
/src
server.js
```

When starting :

```
npm run serve
```

vue.js starts on port 8080

When starting server.js, it starts on port 80

They can't reach together .

For example :

```
app.post("/insertUser", function(req, res)
```

Is trying to connect on port 8080, but I need it to connect to port 80 automatically .

How can I do ?

Thank you.

(PS when the build is done, it is ok, cause it is served by server.js, then all queries are ok on port 80)

Edit : I've seen this https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-setup-vue-dev-server-with-a-running-web-server-7532c53b3198
but config/index.js doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :

Created a **vue.config.js** file like they say there :

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config

Added this inside :

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:80'
  }
}
```